# How to change focus in X-Windows?

Tags: linux, x11, motif

I am working on old Motif-based application for Linux. I want to be able to programmatically change the active window of our application. I can redirect the input by using XSetInputFocus() function and the keyboard input start to go there, but XReconfigureWMWindow() and XRaiseWindow() functions just don't work.

I've read that Window Managers try to stop this behaviour, so tried to disable configure redirection, but this doesn't work either. Any ideas how to make one of my own windows on top of the window stack?

Comment: Hi @theJonan were you able to find a solution on how to focus? I am looking to make a collection of all solutions, so i can create a cross-window-manager solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tiny program called [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) available (at least in Debian/Ubuntu it is in standard distribution) which is able to perform many operations on windows and desktops, and handles plenty of window managers. I'd suggest testing whether it works in your environment, and if so, peeking at its sources.

Comment: As an alternative to wmctrl, see [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer to this is dependent on the Window Manager the user is using, or even what settings they've given to the Window Manager.  I like to set my Window Managers to do "focus follows mouse", which means you can't send the focus to a window that I haven't put my mouse on, unless you also warp the mouse there (is that function called XWarpMouse?).